# Is JavaScript the only way to handle onclick events on an ASP.Net CORE MVC view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can't think of the correct way to phrase the question so here's a bit of detail:

In WebForms on our HTML we could add `OnClick="SomeCodeBehindEvent"` which would do the whole post-back and event handling process.

In ASP.Net CORE I'm unsure how to do the same, for instance on a couple of checkboxes:

```
<div class="form-group form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="UserAccounts" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserAccounts)
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Payments" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Payments)
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="SSL" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SSL)
    </label>
</div>
```

When the user checks `UserAccounts` or `Payments` then `SSL` should automatically check itself.

I know this is possible using JS (or Blazor) - but is there another C#-based  method that fits this design-pattern? I could imagine either in the Model's data annotations, the View or a Controller but not sure what to ask Google - I keep getting JavaScript answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net MVC does not support post-back or event handling. Asp.net MVC provides form validation using data annotation attributes ([Refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)). Which can be used to validate user input on both Client and server side.

But you are trying to change the value of an input based on the values of other inputs in the form. Asp.net MVC does not provide anything to do this. You have to rely on JavaScript to Update the input value.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I did suspect it was the case but hoped I wouldn't have to rely on JS - that's the one thing I miss about WebForms!